# Application code signing

Tags: facebook, sign

Does Facebook mandate any particular level/standards of code signing? It seems to me that using self-signed certificates (rather than reputable roots such as godaddy or globalsign) will work. Am I missing something? I haven't come across clear specs about it.

Thanks,
Dhruv